# PSTricks error "Undefined control sequence <recently read> \c@lor@to@ps"

Tags: errors, xetex, pdftex, pstricks

I have a problem with this file tex:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(1,3.8)
\psline{-<}(0,0)(0,.2)
\psline{-}(0,.2)(0,.4)
\psline{*->}(0,.4)(0,.9)
\psline{-*}(0,.9)(0,1.4)
\psline{-<}(0,1.4)(0,2.4)
\psline{-}(0,2.4)(0,3.4)
\psline{*-}(0,3.4)(0,3.6)
\psline{>-}(0,3.6)(0,3.8)
\rput(1,.4){$y=0$}%testo
\rput(1,1.4){$y=1$}
\rput(1,3.4){$y=3$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

but I don't understand where is the error.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). I think we will need a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) including your preamble.

Comment: It is not related to your problem but it is worth mentioning that it is recommended to use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}...\end{center}`.

Comment: Was there an error message?

Answer (score 45):

It *was* the typical error message when using `pdflatex` with PSTricks. With an up-to-date version you'll get an error message which explains what's the problem.

Run the document with `xelatex` or use the sequence `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` (which is often only one click in a GUI). See also FDE no 4 (Frequently Done Error) at http://PSTricks.tug.org

Comment: This worked for me. Wish I could get the tick beneath the answer :-P but only if it works for the asker!

Comment: Just click the grey tick mark beneath the score on the answer you want to accept. The tick mark will turn green. That means the answer is accepted and everyone will know that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 15):

There is another solution : you *can* use pdfLaTeX with pstricks, provided pdflatex is launched with  one of these switches: `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX) or `--shell-escape` (TeXLive, MacTeX), and you load the `auto-pst-pdf` package *after* pstricks.

Note that if you try to load `xcolor` with an option, there is an `option clash for package 'xcolor'` error message because pstricks already loads xcolor (without option). A work-around consists in adding the xcolor option to the document class options, or writing `PassOptionsToPackage{option}{xcolor}`.

As an example you may begin your document with something like:

```
\usepackage[11pt, a4paper, twoside, x11names, table]{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
```