# Book cover with pstricks

Tags: color, pstricks, covers

Why I get error with the color of the maroon box? (`line 26`)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% load the necessary packages
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=13.24in,margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,prologue,table]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-text}
\usepackage{pst-char}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% begin the document and suppress page numbers
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
% create the box with the front cover picture
\newsavebox\IBox
%%\sbox\IBox{\includegraphics[height=9in]{flower.eps}}
% set up the picture environment
\psset{unit=1in}
\begin{pspicture}(13.24in,9in)
% set up the fonts we use
\DeclareFixedFont{\PT}{T1}{ppl}{b}{it}{0.5in}
\DeclareFixedFont{\PTsmall}{T1}{ppl}{b}{it}{0.4in}
\DeclareFixedFont{\PTsmallest}{T1}{ppl}{b}{it}{0.3in}
\DeclareFixedFont{\PTtext}{T1}{ppl}{b}{it}{11pt}
\DeclareFixedFont{\Logo}{T1}{pbk}{m}{n}{0.3in}
% create a maroon background
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=Maroon](0,0)(13.24,9)
% place the front cover picture
\rput[lb](7.24,0){\usebox\IBox}
% put the text on the front cover
\rput[lb](7.74,7){\PT \color{white}{Secrets of the Stamen}}
\rput[lb](8.94,6){\PTsmall \color{white}{Yuri Robbers}}
\rput[lb](9.04,0.8){\PTsmallest \color{white}{Lughdunum Press}}
% put the text on the spine (note the rotation over 270 degrees)
\rput[l]{270}(6.62,8.5){\PTsmall%
\color{white}{Yuri Robbers --- Secrets of the Stamen}}
% put the publisher’s logo on the spine
\rput[b](6.62,0.75){\color{white}{\fbox{\Logo L}}}
% Create a Box containing the text for the back cover
\newsavebox\Blurbbox
\sbox\Blurbbox{\begin{minipage}{4.5in}
\textcolor{white}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{minipage}}
% And position the box
\rput[tl](1,8){\usebox\Blurbbox}
% Then we close all open environments
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Error

```
linea 26: Undefined control sequence ...tyle=solid,fillcolor=Maroon](0,0)(13.24,9)
linea 26: Undefined control sequence ...tyle=solid,fillcolor=Maroon](0,0)(13.24,9)
linea 26: Undefined control sequence ...tyle=solid,fillcolor=Maroon](0,0)(13.24,9)
linea 26: Undefined control sequence ...tyle=solid,fillcolor=Maroon](0,0)(13.24,9)
linea 26: Undefined control sequence ...tyle=solid,fillcolor=Maroon](0,0)(13.24,9)
linea 26: Undefined control sequence ...tyle=solid,fillcolor=Maroon](0,0)(13.24,9)
linea 0:  ************************************(pst-char) The package `pst-char' is obsolet!(pst-char) You should use `pst-text' directly:(pst-char) \usepackage{pst-text}(pst-char) ************************************.
linea 46: Overfull \hbox (17.62482pt too wide) in paragraph
```

---

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.26 ...tyle=solid,fillcolor=Maroon](0,0)(13.24,9)
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: Ah, it's a classical error. You have to process your document using latex and not pdflatex; the resulting .dvi file can then be converted to pdf format using dvipdf, for example.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks!, really there is not a way to compile it directly with pdflatex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<recently read> `\c@lor@to@ps`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68870/5764).

Comment: @FormlessCloud you can also use xelatex; and I seem to remembre that there's some package(s) allowing to process with pdflatex, but right now I don't remember. Some of the answers by the user with nickname **GarbageCollector** contain information about those packages.

Comment: [see pstricks tag info](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/pstricks/info) voting to close as too localized

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks, I have just add "pdf" at pstriks options..!