# Softmax activation function

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I would like to plot the [softmax activiation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function). I know that there is already a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519666/plotting-softmax-activation-function/519734#519734) but unfortunately neither the comments, nor the answer provided there could really help me so far. This is my current code:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                    ylabel=$\sigma(z)_j$,
                    xlabel=$z$,
                    xmin=-5,
                    xmax=5]
           \addplot[blue,domain=-5:5,samples=51] 
           {exp(x)/sumexp(x,-4,0)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Softmax activation function.}
 \end{figure}
```

Attempting to compile this code always results in the following error message:

> Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `sumexp' (in
> 'exp(x)/sumexp(x,-4,0)'). \end{tikzpicture} }

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

**//edit:**

After adding the following definition (that I foolishly forgot to add before):

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{sumexp}{3}{%
\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{#1}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myxmin}{#2}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myxmax}{#3}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mysum}{0}%
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped\XX in {\myxmin,...,\myxmax}%
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\mysum}{\mysum+exp(\XX)}}%
\pgfmathparse{\mysum+exp(#1)}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%
```

I end up with the following error message:

> Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating
> point unitt was near '-4.0000000000'. (in 'exp(x)/sumexp(x,-4,0)').
> \end{tikzpicture} }

Comment: Looks like you only need to copy the sumexp function definition from the answer in that question.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was missing that. However, if I add this definition, I end up with the following error instead: "Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unitt was near '-4.0000000000'. (in 'exp(x)/sumexp(x,-4,0)'). \end{tikzpicture} }"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the (equivalent) effect of `/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed` is restricted to the very end of function `sumexp` only.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{sumexp}{3}{%
  \begingroup%
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}% "/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed" removed
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{#1}%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myxmin}{#2}%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myxmax}{#3}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mysum}{0}%
  \pgfplotsforeachungrouped\XX in {\myxmin,...,\myxmax}%
    {\pgfmathsetmacro{\mysum}{\mysum+exp(\XX)}}%
  \pgfmathparse{\mysum+exp(#1)}%
  \pgfmathfloattofixed\pgfmathresult%  added
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
                ylabel=$\sigma(z)_j$,
                xlabel=$z$,
                xmin=-5,
                xmax=5]
       \addplot[blue,domain=-5:5,samples=51] 
       {exp(x)/sumexp(x,-4,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please help me check if the plot looks alright since I hardly know anything about the softmax function.

**Some immature words**:

It is `pgfplots` commit [`d2fbb2a`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/commit/d2fbb2a5c2af41c892541a9cd64d82ad60ab6774) that led to the error

> ! Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number `-4.0000000000'. The unreadable part was near ''..

It seems that with `/pgf/fpu=true`, `/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed` doesn't work with `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`, since the latter one may call [`\pgfmathsubtract@` (in `\pgfplotsforeachungroupeduniform@`)](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/blob/3bc2f42258fbfac9fe50b2978459da7e76fc046c/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.code.tex#L774) which, when fpu is activated, always expects input in float format.

Here I employed the possibly easiest change: restrict the scope of `/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed`. In a bigger picture, perhaps the `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` or `\pgfmathsubtract@` should be enhanced.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The plot looks good to me.