# pgfplots: problem with convergence of addplot on (sin(x) - x cos(x)) / x^3

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, equations, asymptote

I am trying to plot the function `f(x) = (sin(x) - x cos(x)) / x^3` using the pgfplots code

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[]
            \addplot[domain = 0:14,smooth,samples=500, thick] {(sin(deg(x))- x * cos(deg(x))) / (x^3)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

The code works, however has problems converging at `x = 0` resulting in an incorrect graph close to the origin:
[image]

Is there anything I can do to circumvent this issue, e.g. by increasing the precision of the addplot command?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered just avoid computation on 0? (for example domain=0.01:14)

Comment: @SergioLlorente At 0 the order is cubic, well beyond arithmetic capabilities of PGF.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to go all the way to 0, then I would suggest using the first terms of the Taylor expansion near 0

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[]
            \addplot[domain = 2:15,smooth,samples=500, thick]
            {(sin(deg(x))- x * cos(deg(x)) ) / (x^3) };
            \addplot[domain = 0:2,smooth,samples=500, thick, red]
            {(1/3 - x^2*4/5! + x^4*6/7! - x^6*8/9!};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here I have coloured the plot of the Taylor expansion red.  Also I have exaggerated the range where the Taylor expansion is used, placing the swap over at 2.  Something smaller than 1, e.g. 0.5, would be more sensible.

Comment: Two terms seem to suffice if you swap at 0.5

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not think of this trick! Works like a charm :)

Comment: @egreg Sure and the quotients can be reduced.  I just wanted to show the general idea.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that the numerator is cubic near 0 and this goes beyond the arithmetic capabilities of PGF.

You can use `pgfmath-xfp` that deals better with floating point calculations. Note that you need to avoid computing at 0, but it's not a real problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfmath-xfp}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmxfpdeclarefunction{foo}{1}{(sin(#1)-(#1)*cos(#1))/(#1)^3}
  \begin{axis}[]
    \addplot[domain = 0.001:14,smooth,samples=500, thick] {foo(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might also define the function at 0, but it's not worth the pain:

```
\pgfmxfpdeclarefunction{foo}{1}{ #1=0 ? 1/3 : (sin(#1)-(#1)*cos(#1))/(#1+(#1=0?1:0))^3}
```

The correction in the denominator is necessary because both expressions are computed, so I make the denominator to be 1 when x=0.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `gnuplot` option which gives much more precision. The compilation must include the `-shell-escape` option.
The `gnuplot` command must be available from your box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[]
          \addplot[domain = 0:14,smooth,samples=500, thick] gnuplot {(sin(x)- x * cos(x)) / (x^3)};
%                                                           ^^^^^^^
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image: graphe]

### Other solution:

You can create a table with any software or programmating language able to do that and save the data in a data file (for instance http://ix.io/3PQw) and use the `table` keyword

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[]
          \addplot[smooth, thick] table {data.dat};
%                                 ^^^^^^^
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

This solution does not need `-shell-escape` but involves slightly slower compilation than the first.
However the first solution is three to four times faster than the solution with `pgfmath-xfp` and nearly five times faster than Andrew Swann's solution.
This may matter on some large documents with lots of calculations.

Answer (score 6):

There comes a time in LaTeX plotting where you have to decide the pros and cons of your method. While LaTeX can handle the basics well, as @egreg points out, the cubic is well beyond the capability of PGF. He goes on to point out `pgfmath-xfp` can deal with floating point issues even better. @Andrew Swann shows that taking advantage of the Taylor series expansion can get you the results you want as well. The more plotting you have to do the more likely you will come up against limitations. The sledgehammer that will solve most any problem is a computer algebra system (CAS). The `sagetex` package gives you access to an open source CAS called [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/) as well as Python programming. Sage is like Mathematica, except it's free.You can access it for free through a [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/). Type the following `plot((sin(x)-x*cos(x))/x^3,(x,-10,14))`, press `Evaluate` and get the result below:
[image]

A CAS has the power to handle the mathematics more accurately. You can use the CAS to generate the points, and use `tizk` to plot them via the `sagetex` package.

Here is some sample code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
LowerX = 0.001
UpperX = 14
LowerY = -.1
UpperY = .35
step = .1
t = var('t')
g(x)= (sin(x)-x*cos(x))/x^3

x_coords = [t for t in srange(LowerX,UpperX,step)]
y_coords = [g(t).n(digits=6) for t in srange(LowerX,UpperX,step)]

output = r""
output += r"\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]"
output += r"\begin{axis}[xmin=%f,xmax=%f,ymin= %f,ymax=%f,width=10cm]"%(LowerX,UpperX,LowerY, UpperY)
output += r"\addplot[thin, blue, unbounded coords=jump] coordinates {"
for i in range(0,len(x_coords)-1):
    if (y_coords[i])<LowerY or (y_coords[i])>UpperY:
        output += r"(%f , inf) "%(x_coords[i])
    else:
        output += r"(%f , %f) "%(x_coords[i],y_coords[i])
output += r"};"
output += r"\end{axis}"
output += r"\end{tikzpicture}"
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

The output, running in Cocalc is below:
[image]

The drawback is Sage is not part of a LaTeX distribution. The easiest way to work with it is through a free [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) account. Less easy is to install Sage on your computer and get it to work with your LaTeX distribution. I've had some problems doing this in Windows but Linux hasn't been difficult.

If you're using mathematics frequently, Sage and `sagetex` are worth the time and effort learning.
Search this site for `sagetex` examples. The Cantor function, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241622/plotting-the-cantor-function) and the Weierstrass function [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156993/plotting-weierstrass-function) can be plotted without much difficulty.

The documentation for `sagetex` is [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex?lang=en).

Answer (score 5):

Just to complete Andrew's answer, you can use `x ? y : z` notation to make it with only one `\addplot`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[]
          \addplot[domain = 0:15,smooth,samples=500, thick]
          { abs(x)>0.5 ? 
            (sin(deg(x))- x * cos(deg(x)) ) / (x^3) :
            (1/3 - x^2*4/5! + x^4*6/7! - x^6*8/9!
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

From pgfmanual:
`x ? y : z` ? and : are special operators which can be used as a shorthand for if x then y else z inside the parser

Answer (score 4):

Just notice that Asymptote, with high accuracy, is a straight way to draw such functions. I add `f(0)=1/3` (see [this Wolfram Alpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%28x%29%20%3D%20%28sin%28x%29%20-%20x%20cos%28x%29%29%20%2F%20x%5E3%20Taylor%20expansion%20at%20x%3D0)), then draw its graph as usual, no tricks. `operator..` is used for this smooth function.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(5mm,20cm);
import graph;
real f(real x){
if (x==0) return 1/3;
else  return (sin(x) - x * cos(x)) / (x^3);
}

path p=graph(f,0,15,operator..);
//path p=graph(f,-15,15,operator..);
draw(p,red+1pt);

xaxis("$x$",BottomTop,LeftTicks);
yaxis("$y$",LeftRight,RightTicks(trailingzero));

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

[image]