# Problem with \psshadowbox

Tags: pdf, pstricks, a0poster

Why doesn't this work? I think I've got all the packeges I need, and I've copied it from http://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-3/morales/morales.pdf.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,final]{a0poster}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-grad}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\psshadowbox[linewidth=1mm,framearc=0.1,linecolor=red,framesep=1em]{
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.5\linewidth}
{\bf Fermat’s last theorem}
If an integer $n$ is greater than $2$, then the equation
$$ a^n+b^n=c^n $$
has no solutions in non-zero integers $a$, $b$, and $c$.
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works without problem. Either you are compiling with `pdflatex` (rather than `latex` or `xelatex`; see [PSTricks error “Undefined control sequence <recently read> `\c@lor@to@ps`”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68870/5764)) or you have an outdated package somewhere? See [Which package version am I using?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,final]{a0poster}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-grad}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\psshadowbox[linewidth=1mm,framearc=0.1,linecolor=red,framesep=1em]{%
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.5\linewidth}
{\bf Fermat’s last theorem}
If an integer $n$ is greater than $2$, then the equation
$$ a^n+b^n=c^n $$
has no solutions in non-zero integers $a$, $b$, and $c$.
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, now it works. I also found some other options how to use pstricks in pdfLaTeX, but it was too complicated for nothing and there was always something missing.