# psmatrix error - Undefined control sequence

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add, psmatrix

When executing the following code, I get the error:

> ```
> Undefined control sequence. 
> <recently read> \c@lor@to@ps l.7 [name=A] 1 & [name=B] 8 \\[0pt] ?
> ```

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
\begin{psmatrix}[fillstyle=solid,mnode=circle,colsep=1]
[name=A] 1 & [name=B] 8 \\[0pt]
[name=C] 2 & [name=D] 9
\end{psmatrix}
\end{document}
```

I have updated my packages as well but no affect.

Comment: See [PSTricks error “Undefined control sequence <recently read> \c@lor@to@ps”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68870/33933).

Comment: See my answer added to the above link, to compile with `pdflatex`.

Comment: @Bernard in the command prompt I give `pdflatex --enable-write18 test.tex` with the document class as `\documentclass[12pt, pdf]{article}`, I get the same error. The packages I have used are : `\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}`

Comment: @subhamsoni: quite strange… I have no problem, whether from my editor or from the command line. You're using MiKTeX, not TeX Live? Is `auto-pst-pdf` installed? The `pdf` option just loads auto-pst-pdf, that does all the job.

Comment: I am using `latex-dvi-ps-pdf` way.....