# How to install pstricks

Tags: pstricks, installing

I want to install PSTricks (I use Texmaker). I have downloaded the files from the following page:
http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi
but nowhere do they say where the files should be copied or how the package should be installed.
Can someone help me? I am new to latex.

This is what i get :

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.142 ...ddiv=0,gridlabels=0](0,0)(-16,-12)(13,24)
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...string \color@ #1#2\endcsname \@@
\fi \space
l.142 ...ddiv=0,gridlabels=0](0,0)(-16,-12)(13,24)
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: Have you got a TeX system installed? Any modern system should have PSTricks available.

Comment: I have texlive, but still can't use pstricks. I am trying to read a tex file which uses pstricks, but I have the "undefined control sequence" error whenever it calls a pstricks function...

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit in the question: is this perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68870/pstricks-error-undefined-control-sequence-recently-read-clortops

Comment: yes this is exactly the error i have

Comment: Problem solved ! I did dvi to ps, then ps to pdf. Thank you very much @Joseph Wright !

Comment: Using XeLaTeX gives you some features you might desire.

Comment: TeX Live usually does a complete install coming with PSTricks as well. If you want to install or update packages, please use the *TeX Live Manager8 (`tlmgr`). Installing packages manually is an error prone method.

Comment: @Asinus No problem: this is an issue that once you know about it is very easy to spot