# Automatically generate multiplication table and colour specific rown, columns, and diagonals

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks

Consider the following PSTricks code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks,multido}
\psset{dimen = m, fillstyle = solid}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(12,12)
    \psframe[fillcolor = orange](0,11)(1,12)
    \rput(0.5,11.5){$\cdot$}
    \multido{\iA = 1+1, \iB = 10+-1}{11}{
      \psframe[fillcolor = orange](\iA,11)(!\iA\space 1 add 12)
      \rput(!\iA\space 0.5 add 11.5){$\iA$}
      \psframe[fillcolor = orange](0,\iB)(!1 \iB\space 1 add)
      \rput(!0.5 \iB\space 0.5 add){$\iA$}
      \multido{\iC = 0+1}{11}{\psframe(\iA,\iC)(!\iA\space 1 add \iC\space 1 add)}}
  \end{pspicture}
 \caption{Multiplication table.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Questions**

- How do I automatically genrate the numbers in the multiplication table? (I've had a look at the code in [section 14 of the `pstricks-add` manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pstricks-add/doc/pstricks-add-doc.pdf#page=29) but without any luck.)
- How (if possible) do I automatically colour all the squares in the sequence, say, n*(n+6) (i.e., the two diagonals of squares containing the numbers 6, 14, 24, 36, 50, 66)?

P.S. If no PSTricks solution can be found, a Ti*k*Z solution is also acceptable but I prefer PSTricks. `:)`

**Update**

I should probably add that I only need rows, column, or diagonals coloured; not, say, 4, 15, 30, 49, 72, 99. (If someone can come up with code that can automatically colour such a sequence, it will of course be even better but it's not necessary.)

**Update 2**

Here is what I now have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks,multido}
\psset{dimen = m, fillstyle = solid}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\def\tableSize{11}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(\calc{\tableSize+1},\calc{\tableSize+1})
    \psframe[fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = orange](0,\tableSize)(1,\calc{\tableSize+1})
    \rput(0.5,\calc{\tableSize+0.5}){$\cdot$}
    \multido{\iA = 1+1, \iB = \calc{\tableSize-1}+-1}{\tableSize}{%
      \psframe[fillcolor = orange](\iA,\tableSize)(\calc{\iA+1},\calc{\tableSize+1})
      \rput(\calc{\iA+0.5},\calc{\tableSize+0.5}){$\iA$}
      \psframe[fillcolor = orange](0,\iB)(1,\calc{\iB+1})
      \rput(0.5,\calc{\iB+0.5}){$\iA$}
      \multido{\iC = 1+1}{\tableSize}{%
        \psframe(\iA,\calc{\tableSize+1-\iC})(\calc{\iA+1},\calc{\tableSize-\iC})
        \rput(\calc{\iA+0.5},\calc{\tableSize+0.5-\iC}){$\calc{\iA*\iC}$}}}
  \end{pspicture}
 \caption{Multiplication table.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

---

I found a PSTricks solution myself where arbitrary "horizontal", "vertical", and "diagonal" series can be colored.

**Macro syntax**

```
\tableColorRow[<row color>]{<now number>}
\tableColorColumn[<column color>]{<column number>}
\tableColorDiagonal[<diagonal color>]{<starting row/column number>}
```

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks,multido}
\usepackage{bm}

\psset{dimen = m, fillstyle = solid}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

% create table
\def\tableArithmetic[#1]#2{%
  \psframe[fillcolor = #1](0,\tableSize)(1,\calc{\tableSize+1})
  \rput(0.5,\calc{\tableSize+0.5}){$\boldsymbol{#2}$}
  \multido{\iA = 1+1, \iB = \calc{\tableSize-1}+-1}{\tableSize}{%
    \psframe[fillcolor = #1](\iA,\tableSize)(\calc{\iA+1},\calc{\tableSize+1})
    \rput(\calc{\iA+0.5},\calc{\tableSize+0.5}){\fontSize $\iA$}
    \psframe[fillcolor = #1](0,\iB)(1,\calc{\iB+1})
    \rput(0.5,\calc{\iB+0.5}){\fontSize $\iA$}
    \multido{\iC = 1+1}{\tableSize}{%
      \psframe(\iA,\calc{\tableSize+1-\iC})(\calc{\iA+1},\calc{\tableSize-\iC})
      \rput(\calc{\iA+0.5},\calc{\tableSize+0.5-\iC}){\fontSize $\calc{\iA*\iC}$}%
    }%
  }%
}
% color row
\def\tableColorRow[#1]#2{%
  \multido{\i = 1+1}{\tableSize}{%
    \psframe[fillcolor = #1](\i,\calc{\tableSize-#2})(\calc{\i+1},\calc{\tableSize-#2+1})
    \rput(\calc{\i+0.5},\calc{\tableSize-#2+0.5}){\fontSize $\calc{\i*#2}$}%
  }%
}
% color column
\def\tableColorColumn[#1]#2{%
  \multido{\iA = 1+1, \iB = \calc{\tableSize-1}+-1}{\tableSize}{%
    \psframe[fillcolor = #1](#2,\iB)(\calc{#2+1},\calc{\iB+1})
    \rput(\calc{#2+0.5},\calc{\iB+0.5}){\fontSize $\calc{\iA*#2}$}%
  }%
}
% color diagonal
\def\tableColorDiagonal[#1]#2{%
  \multido{\iA = 1+1, \iB = #2+1, \iC = \calc{\tableSize-#2}+-1, \iD = \calc{\tableSize-1}+-1}{\calc{\tableSize-#2+1}}{%
    \psframe[fillcolor = #1](\iA,\iC)(\calc{\iA+1},\calc{\iC+1})
    \rput(\calc{\iA+0.5},\calc{\iC+0.5}){\fontSize $\calc{\iA*(\iA+#2-1)}$}
    \psframe[fillcolor = #1](\iB,\iD)(\calc{\iB+1},\calc{\iD+1})
    \rput(\calc{\iB+0.5},\calc{\iD+0.5}){\fontSize $\calc{\iA*(\iA+#2-1)}$}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\def\tableSize{11}
\def\fontSize{%
%  \Huge
%  \huge
%  \LARGE
%  \Large
%  \large
  \normalsize
%  \small
%  \footnotesize
%  \scriptsize
%  \tiny
}
 \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(\calc{\tableSize+1},\calc{\tableSize+1})
    \tableArithmetic[orange!80]{\cdot}
    \tableColorRow[blue!70]{8}
    \tableColorColumn[red!70]{2}
    \tableColorDiagonal[green!80]{6}
  \end{pspicture}
 \caption{Multiplication table.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: output]

Comment: Shouldn't `n * (n+6)` color `7 = 1 * 7`, `16 = 2 * 8`, `27 = 3 * 9`, etc?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Indeed it shall. `:)`

Comment: @ChenStatsYu http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68870/pstricks-error-undefined-control-sequence-recently-read-clortops

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A mixture of bits and pieces from various answers on this page and the OP's code...

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=5]{standalone}    
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff    
\psset{dimen = m, fillstyle = solid}
\begin{document} 
\def\N{11}
\begin{pspicture}(\calc{\N+1},\calc{\N+1})
\psframe[fillcolor = orange](!0 \N\space 1 add)(1,\N)
\rput(!0.5 \N\space 0.5 add){$\cdot$}     
\foreach \i in {1,...,\N}{
  \psframe[fillcolor = orange](\i, \N)(\calc{\i+1}, \calc{\N+1})
  \rput(\calc{\i+.5}, \calc{\N+.5}){$\i$}
  \psframe[fillcolor = orange](0, \calc{\N-\i})(1, \calc{\N-\i+1})
  \rput(0.5, \calc{\N-\i+.5}){$\i$}
}     
\foreach \iA in {1,...,\N}{\foreach \iB in {1,...,\N}{
    \edef\x{\calc{abs(\iA-\iB)}} 
    \ifnum\x=5
      \colorlet{fill color}{blue!20}
    \else
      \colorlet{fill color}{white}
    \fi
    \psframe[fillcolor=fill color](\iA, \calc{\N-\iB})(\calc{\iA+1}, \calc{\N-\iB+1})
    \rput(\calc{\iA+.5}, \calc{\N-\iB+.5}){$\calc{\iA*\iB}$} 
}}
\end{pspicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: PSTricks loads basic `pgffor,pgfmath` for some reason.

Answer (score 8):

In case TikZ needed,

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\def\mcr{\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}\def\mcc{\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[border style/.style={
    draw,fill=#1,minimum size=0.8cm,anchor=center,outer sep=0,
    name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\mcr-\the\mcc
}]
\matrix[row sep=-.5*\pgflinewidth,column sep=-.5*\pgflinewidth,
   execute at empty cell={%
       \ifnum1=\mcr\relax%
           \ifnum1=\mcc\relax\node[border style=red]{$\cdot$};%
           \else\node[border style=red]{$\number\numexpr\the\mcc-1\relax$};\fi
       \else%
         \ifnum1=\mcc\relax\node[border style=red]{$\cdot$};%
           \node[border style=red]{$\number\numexpr\the\mcr-1\relax$};%
         \else%
           \pgfmathparse{int(abs(\mcr-\mcc))}%
           \ifnum5=\pgfmathresult\relax\def\temp{yellow}\else\def\temp{none}\fi%
           \node[border style=\temp]{\number\numexpr\numexpr\the\mcc-1\relax*\numexpr\the\mcr-1\relax\relax};%
         \fi%
       \fi}
] (a) {
&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice. I don't know Ti*k*Z so can I make you explain how you colour the diagonals? Also, is it possible to create a macro, say `\multiTable{<size>}{<diagonals to colour + colour used>}`, to generate the table (since I need more of them)?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg It is cheating. If the difference between the row number and the column number is exactly 5 then I change the fill color. It is the last part of the if branch. It is the index of the 5th sub super diagonal.

Comment: Okay. I'll have a look at it; thank you very much.

Comment: Very nice. Is there a way to change the code slightly to avoid having to hard code the ampersands? that is, replacing the lines``&&&&&&&&&&&\\`` with something 'more general', so that the size of the matrix could be changed without having to recode? Thanks. (I can ask a separate question if you think it deserves it!)

Answer (score 8):

This seems like overkill (and it is) but you have high customizability.

The automatic building of the matrix is done via two loops that adds the correct amount of `\pgfmatrixnextcell`s and `\\`s in one macro that solely is given to the `matrix` content. There might be better ways, but this is the easiest I have found for now.

`\pgfmathloop` is—as far as I know—LaTeX’s `\loop` with an included counter (`\pgfmathcounter`, a macro) and does not group and is very much without any other functionality like PGF’s own `\foreach`, but for this it suffices.

There is much more room for improvement like hiding the `\pgfmatrix…` internals from the outside, e.g. interacting with the headings in a separate way, having the first row be the actual first row with contents, etc.

I have added a second diagram that uses the function row<sup>columns</sup> for calculating a cell’s content. The second column (i.e. the first after the header column) is altered with the style

```
column 2/.style={coordinate, column sep=+0pt},
```

which changes the `column sep` back to zero (the `-\pgflinewidth` sep is needed as you want the lines to overlap) and applies `coordinate` (i.e. `shape=coordinate`) to the nodes with essentially eliminates the node (and its text). Of course TikZ still creates a named coordinate and all …

Here further functions for the columns/rows would be helpful.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
  if/.code n args=3{\pgfmathparse{#1}\ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
    \pgfkeysalso{#3}\else\pgfkeysalso{#2}\fi},
  set column text width/.style={
    /utils/exec=\pgfmathtruncatemacro\multiTableTempa{#1-1}%
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\multiTableTempb{multiTableFunction(\multiTableRows,\multiTableTempa)},
    column #1/.append style/.expanded={every node/.append style={text width=width("\multiTableTempb")}}},
  multiplication table/.style={
    matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells,
    column sep=+-\pgflinewidth, row sep=+-\pgflinewidth,
    cells={nodes={outer sep=+0pt,
      if={(\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1)*(\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1)==0}{}{multiTable every node/.try}}},
    row 1/.style={nodes={
      if={\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn==1}{}{node contents=\pgfmathprint{int(\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1)}},
      multiTable first row/.try}},
    column 1/.style={nodes={
      if={\pgfmatrixcurrentrow==1}{}{node contents=\pgfmathprint{int(\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1)}},
      multiTable first column/.try}},
    row 1 column 1/.append style={nodes={align=center,
      node contents={\cdot},multiTable tr/.try}},
    every cell/.append style={
      nodes={
        minimum size=+1.5em, draw, align=right,
        text height=+.7\baselineskip, text depth=+0\baselineskip,
        if={and(\pgfmatrixcurrentrow>1,\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn>1)}{
          node contents={\pgfmathprint{multiTableFunction(\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1,\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1)}},
        }{}}}},
  multiTable first row/.style={fill=orange!50},
  multiTable first column/.style={fill=orange!50},
  multiTable tr/.style={fill=orange!20},
  multiTable def function/.style={multiTable set function={int(\r*\c)}},
  multiTable set function/.style={declare function={multiTableFunction(\r,\c)=#1;}}}
\newcommand*\addTo[2]{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\newcommand*\multiplicationTable[3][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\multiTableRows{#2}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\multiTableColumns{#3}
\def\multiTableTempa{}
\pgfmathloop
  \addTo\multiTableTempa{\pgfmatrixnextcell}
  \ifnum\pgfmathcounter<\multiTableColumns
\repeatpgfmathloop
\addTo\multiTableTempa{\\}\let\multiTableSetupFinal\multiTableTempa
\pgfmathloop
  \expandafter\addTo\expandafter\multiTableSetupFinal\expandafter{\multiTableTempa}
  \ifnum\pgfmathcounter<\multiTableRows
\repeatpgfmathloop
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\multiTableTempb{\multiTableColumns+1}
\matrix[multiplication table,
  set column text width/.list={2,...,\multiTableTempb},
  column 1/.append style/.expanded={nodes={text width=width("\multiTableRows")}},
]{\multiTableSetupFinal};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\multiplicationTable[
  multiTable def function,
  every cell/.append style={
    if={(abs(\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)==6)}{nodes={fill=red!50}}{}},
  ]{10}{10}
\multiplicationTable[
  multiTable set function={int(\r^\c)},
  multiTable tr/.append style={node contents=r^c,fill=blue!20},
  column 2/.style={coordinate, column sep=+0pt},
  multiTable first row/.style={fill=blue!50},
  multiTable first column/.style={fill=blue!50},
  multiTable every node/.style={text=blue},% blue enough?
  ]{10}{4}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There is no need for PSTricks or Ti*k*Z, the good old environment `picture` will do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color} 

\newcounter{cntA}
\newcounter{cntB}
\newcommand*{\makerule}[2]{%
  \makebox(#1,#2){%
    \rule{#1\unitlength}{#2\unitlength}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \mbox{%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\linewidth}%
    \addtolength{\unitlength}{-.4pt}% half line width left and right
    \hspace{.2pt}%
    \begin{picture}(1, 1)
      \divide\unitlength by 12\relax
      % Draw background of header cells
      \textcolor{orange}{%
        \put(0, 0){\makerule{1}{12}}
        \put(0, 11){\makerule{12}{1}}
      }%
      % Set header cells
      \put(0, 11){\makebox(1, 1){$\times$}}
      \setcounter{cntA}{0}%
      \multiput(1, 11)(1, 0){11}{%
        \stepcounter{cntA}%
        \makebox(1, 1){\thecntA}%
      }
      \multiput(0, 0)(0, 1){11}{%
        \makebox(1, 1){\thecntA}%
        \addtocounter{cntA}{-1}%
      }
      % Color diagonals
      \textcolor{yellow}{%
        \multiput(1, 5)(1, -1){6}{\makerule{1}{1}}%
        \multiput(6, 10)(1, -1){6}{\makerule{1}{1}}%
      }%
      % Set body cells
      \setcounter{cntA}{0}%
      \multiput(1, 10)(0, -1){11}{%
        \stepcounter{cntA}%
        \setcounter{cntB}{0}%
        \multiput(0, 0)(1, 0){11}{%
          \stepcounter{cntB}%
          \makebox(1, 1){\the\numexpr\value{cntA}*\value{cntB}\relax}%
        }%
      }   
      % Draw lines
      \multiput(0, 0)(0, 1){13}{\line(1, 0){12}}
      \multiput(0, 0)(1, 0){13}{\line(0, 1){12}}
    \end{picture}%
    \hspace{.2pt}%
  }%
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

MetaPost is another adequate candidate for this kind of pictures.

```
input mpcolornames; color myorange; myorange = .5[Red,Yellow];
input latexmp; setupLaTeXMP(mode = rerun, textextlabel = enable);
u := 1cm;
def loc(expr i,j) = 
  ((i-.5, -.5-j) -- (i+.5, -.5-j) -- (i+.5, .5-j) -- (i-.5, .5-j) -- cycle) scaled u
enddef;
beginfig(1);
  fill loc(0, 0) withcolor myorange; label(".", origin); 
  for i = 1 upto 11:
    fill loc(i, 0) withcolor myorange;
    label(decimal i, (i*u, 0));
    fill loc(0, i) withcolor myorange;
    label(decimal i, (0, -i*u));
  endfor
  % Filling
  for i = 1 upto 11:
    for j = 1 upto 11:
      if abs(i-j) = 5: fill loc(i,j) withcolor Yellow; fi
      label(decimal(i*j), u*(i, -j));
    endfor
  endfor
  % Grid lines
  for i = 0 upto 12:
    draw u*(i-0.5, .5) -- u*(i-0.5, -11.5);
    draw u*(-0.5, 0.5-i) -- u*(11.5, 0.5-i);
  endfor;
endfig;
end.
```

For each pair `(i,j)` of integers, the macro `loc(i,j)` gives its location in the table (the square which contains `i*j`, in this order), and the following instruction fills this location with yellow color if `|i-j|=5`:

```
if abs(i-j) = 5: fill loc(i,j) withcolor Yellow; fi
```

Result:

[image]