# crossing columns in package sgame

Tags: matrices

I am using the package sgame for drawing strategic-form games for my thesis on game theory. Everything works fine, but I do not know how to cross rows or columns which are dominated. I found a very helpful script on

https://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/latex/sgame.pdf

but the offered solution with

```
 \def\sgtextcolor{black}%
 \def\sglinecolor{black}%
 \newcommand\redStrike[2]{%
    \ncline[linewidth=1.2pt,nodesep=-14pt,linecolor=red]{#1}{#2}}

 \begin{game}{2}{2}
 &\rnode[t]{a12}{$L$}       &$R$\\
 \Rnode[href=20]{a21}{$T$}  &$1,1$ &\Rnode{a23}{$2,2$}\\
 $B$ &\rnode[b]{a32}{$2,2$} &$3,3$
 \end{game}
 % specify the nodes to be connected
 \redStrike{a21}{a23}
 \redStrike{a12}{a32}
```

does somehow not work in my script. Is there any other solution to my problem?
This is how my matrix looks:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{game}{2}{2}[\textbf{S}][\textbf{T}]
        & G & S \\
        W & (10,5) & (0,-5)        \\
        L & (5,10) & (-5,0)        
    \end{game}
 \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from the manual uses `pstricks`. This package should be used with the `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` compiler sequence (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68871/89417) instead of the modern `pdflatex` compiler.

If you want to use `pdflatex` then you can use `tikz` instead. You can define empty tikz nodes at the position of the `sgame` cells and draw a line between those. This is a bit less clean because it involves manual spacing of the cells.

MWE for `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sgame}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\newcommand{\strike}[2]{\ncline[linewidth=1pt,nodesep=-14pt]{#1}{#2}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{game}{2}{2}[\textbf{S}][\textbf{T}]
        & G & \rnode[t]{a}{S} \\
        W & (10,5) & (0,-5)        \\
        L & (5,10) & \rnode[b]{b}{(-5,0)}        
    \end{game}
    \strike{a}{b}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

MWE for `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sgame}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{game}{2}{2}[\textbf{S}][\textbf{T}]
        & G & \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] \node (a) {\phantom{S}}; \end{tikzpicture} \hspace*{-3mm} S \\
        W & (10,5) & (0,-5)        \\
        L & (5,10) & \hspace*{5mm}\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] \node (b) {\phantom{S}}; \draw (a.north) -- (b.south); \end{tikzpicture} \hspace*{-7mm} (-5,0)       
    \end{game}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]