# PDFLatex, tikz, simple flows, ! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \c@lor@to@ps

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I wanted to draw a simple protocol flow using the `tikz` package. However, I got some errors and really don't know how to deal with them.

Here's the code in `LaTeX`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-base,tkz-fct}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{msc}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!h]
\center
\resizebox{12cm}{!} {
\begin{msc}{$IJS_{NK, dec/enc}$}
\small
\setlength{\instwidth}{1.7 cm}
\setlength{\instdist}{2.3 cm}
\setlength{\bottomfootdist}{0.2 cm}
%\setlength{\instwidth}{2 cm}
%\setlength{\instdist}{3.75 cm}
\setlength{\envinstdist}{1.2 cm}
\setlength{\topheaddist}{0.5 cm}
\instfoot

\declinst{I}{\scriptsize new node}{$I$} 
\declinst{R}{\scriptsize neighbour node}{$R$}
\declinst{J1k-1}{\scriptsize intermediate nodes}{$J_{1:k-1}$}
\declinst{Jk}{\scriptsize \:\: intermediate node}{$J_{k}$}
\declinst{S}{\scriptsize Sink}{$S$}

% left to right messages
\mess{$m_1 = \{n_I, I, R\}_{K_{DH}(I,S)}$}{I}{R}
\nextlevel
\mess{$\{n_R, m_1\}_{NK}$}{R}{J1k-1}
\nextlevel
\mess{$\{n_{J_{k-1}}, ..., n_{J_1}, n_R, m_1\}_{NK}$}{J1k-1}{Jk}
\nextlevel
\mess{$\{n_{J_k}, ..., n_{J_1}, n_R, m_1\}_{NK}$}{Jk}{S}
\nextlevel

% right to left messages
\nextlevel
\mess{$\{n_{J_k}, ..., n_{J_1}, n_R, m_2\}_{NK}$}{S}{Jk}
\nextlevel
\mess{$\{n_{J_{k-1}}, ..., n_{J_1}, n_R, m_2\}_{NK}$}{Jk}{J1k-1}
\nextlevel
\mess{$\{n_R, m_2\}_{NK}$}{J1k-1}{R}
\nextlevel
\mess{$m_3$}{R}{I}
%\nextlevel
\end{msc}
}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{11.5 cm}
$m_2 = \{pk(I), \{n_I, I, R, S\}_{K_{DH}(I,S)}\}_{K_{DH}(R,S)}$\\
$m_3 = \{K(R,I), \{n_I, I, R, S\}_{K_{DH}(I,S)} \}_{pk(I)}$
\end{minipage} 
}
\caption{$IJS_{NK, dec/enc}$: Proof by Induction.}
\label{figure : IJS-NK-dec-enc Induction}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

I compile it in console using: `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode toc.tex`.

My pdflatex version is:

```
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.2.49; using libpng 1.2.50
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.24.5
```

However, I'm using it "inside" `TeXMaker` on `Kubuntu 14.04`.

`pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode toc.tex > errors.txt`:

Here's the `*.log` file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/29dc1550a6cd56d8aa34c193ed86154b, and the errors https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4bbb648cc2ee48468dfc071318e09380.

`xelatex toc.tex > xelatexerrors.txt`:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c609d4f3d784ee47635814f7b88f578a

`latex toc.tex > latexerrors.txt`:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8994caae091854df757d6bc6c6dcff33

Adding `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` produced an empty pdf (I did `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode toc.tex > errors.txt`), here're the erros: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6f85b7732a1acb5dc3ab31707edc8400

[image]

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68870/pstricks-error-undefined-control-sequence-recently-read-clortops

Comment: @JosephWright♦: None of the answears helped

Comment: I just ran your example with the classical (`latex` + `dvips` + `ps2pdf`) route and all is fine bar `\instfoot` being undefined, which does not prevent production of output.

Comment: @JosephWright♦: I tried: `latex toc.tex` (`Enter`), `dvips toc.dvi `, `pstopdf toc.ps ` but the image does not look very good: https://s15.postimg.org/vcheufbuz/shoot2.png

Comment: Yes, but 'Doesn't look very good' doesn't mean the code isn't working! I get the same, and take it to be the 'expected' output of what is quite a lot of input for a construct I'm not familiar with.