# Periodic Table code not working

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, compiling, brackets

Good evening,

I wanted to run the following code (it's part of the PSTRICKS Examples list, so you can check it for free) but it does not work. There are two errors, in lines 165 and 390 which I do not understand.

They involve } brackets, which seem to be put there for a reason (which I don't know). If I take them off the code won't even start to be compiled.

Any help?

Thank you!

```
    \documentclass[12pt,table]{article}% Thomas Soell

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[scaled=.95]{helvet}
\usepackage{lscape}

\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathord}{letters}{"3B}
%\usepackage[%
%    driver=dvips,
%    web={pro},
%    uselayers,
%    eforms={useui},
%    aebxmp
%]{aeb_pro}


\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,array}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage[distiller]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-grad,pst-text}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

 \addtolength{\topmargin}{-3.7cm}
 \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.0cm}
 \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-1.0cm}
%------------------------------------------
 \textheight28cm
 \textwidth19cm
%------------------------------------------

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} %\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\pagestyle{empty}

%% Setzen der R\"{a}nder und Dimensionen (kommt von "web")
%\margins{2.3cm}{2cm}{2cm}{1.7cm}     %% Kein Seitenrand
%\screensize{21cm}{29.7cm}        %% Dimensionen: H\"{o}he, Breite des Dokuments


\newpsstyle{Leer}{fillstyle=solid,framesep=0pt,linewidth=.2pt,fillcolor=white,linecolor=white}
\newpsstyle{Wst}{fillstyle=gradient,framesep=0pt,linewidth=.2pt,gradbegin=yellow!10,gradend=yellow!30,gradmidpoint=0,gradangle=45,dimen=middle}
\newpsstyle{Alk}{fillstyle=gradient,framesep=0pt,linewidth=.2pt,gradbegin=blue!40,gradend=blue!60,gradmidpoint=0,gradangle=45,dimen=middle}
\newpsstyle{EAlk}{fillstyle=gradient,framesep=0pt,linewidth=.2pt,gradbegin=blue!10,gradend=blue!30,gradmidpoint=0,gradangle=45,dimen=middle}
\newpsstyle{Metall}{fillstyle=gradient,framesep=0pt,linewidth=.2pt,gradbegin=cyan!50!black!40,gradend=cyan!20!black!20,gradmidpoint=0,gradangle=45}
\newpsstyle{HalbMet}{fillstyle=gradient,framesep=0pt,linewidth=.2pt,gradbegin=orange!20,gradend=orange!40,gradmidpoint=0,gradangle=45}
\newpsstyle{NoMetal}{fillstyle=gradient,framesep=0pt,linewidth=.2pt,gradbegin=green!40!cyan!60,gradend=green!20!cyan!40,gradmidpoint=0,gradangle=45}
\newpsstyle{Halogen}{fillstyle=gradient,framesep=0pt,linewidth=.2pt,gradbegin=green!70!blue!70,gradend=green!40!blue!40,gradmidpoint=0,gradangle=45}
\newpsstyle{Edel}{fillstyle=gradient,framesep=0pt,linewidth=.2pt,gradbegin=green!40,gradend=green!60,gradmidpoint=0,gradangle=45,dimen=middle}
\newpsstyle{LantAct}{fillstyle=gradient,linewidth=.2pt,gradbegin=magenta!10!brown!30,gradend=magenta!20!brown!50,gradmidpoint=0,gradangle=45}

\newcommand{\Gase}{red}
\newcommand{\Fluessig}{blue!90!black!70}

%% Dokumentdeklarationen
%\DeclareDocInfo{%
%     title={Periodensystem der Elemente},
%     author={Thomas S\"{o}ll},
%     subject={Periodensystem mit PSTricks},
%     copyrightStatus=True,
%     copyrightNotice={\u00A9 \the\year, TS},
%%% Copyright (Sonderzeichen per Unicode - http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/)
%     copyrightInfoURL=http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/G/mathe/Extras/
%}

%\begin{docassembly}
%\executeSave();
%\end{docassembly}


\begin{document}

\parindent0pt
\begin{landscape}

\pagecolor{brown!15}

\newcommand{\Element}[6]
{\psset{style=#6}%
\begin{pspicture}(0,0.075)(2.75,2.67)
     \psframe(0,0)(2.75,2.75)%
       \rput[l](0.3,2.2){\small\textbf{#1}}%
       \rput[r](2.4,2.2){\small#2}%
       \rput(1.35,1.35){\textbf{\LARGE #3}}%
       \rput(1.35,0.5){\small#4}
       \rput[r](2.4,0.9){\textcolor{red}{\small#5}}
\end{pspicture}
}

\newcommand{\ElementLegende}[6]
{\psset{style=#6}%
\begin{pspicture}(0,0.075)(2.75,2.67)
     \psframe(0,0)(2.75,2.75)%
       \rput[l](0.3,2.2){\small\textbf{#1}}%
       \rput[r](2.4,2.2){\small#2}%
       \rput(1.35,1.35){\textbf{\LARGE #3}}%
       \rput(1.35,0.5){\small#4}
       \rput[r](2.4,0.9){\textcolor{red}{\small#5}}
\end{pspicture}
}




\DeclareFixedFont{\TSLarge}{T1}{phv}{b}{n}{0.8cm}
\newcommand{\Ueberschrift}[1]%
{%
\pscharpath[shadow=false,
    fillstyle=gradient,
    gradend=black!70,
    gradbegin=cyan!50!black!80,
    linestyle=solid,
    linecolor=black,
    linestyle=none]{\TSLarge #1}
}

\newcommand{\fuellschrift}[1]%
{%
\pscharpath[shadow=false,
    fillstyle=solid,
    fillcolor=white,
    opacity=0.6,
    linestyle=solid,
    linecolor=black,
    linewidth=.5pt]{\LARGE #1}
}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}p{2.75cm}}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\Centering}p{1.5cm}}
\tabcolsep=0pt%\bfseries%

\centering{Periodensystem der Elemente mit PSTricks}

%----- Legende ---------------------------------------------------------
\rput(6.5,5){%
\psscalebox{.5}{%
\begin{tabular}{lcllrll}
\psframe[style=Alk](0,-0.05)(0.4,0.35) \hspace{0.5cm} Alkalimetalle     &\rule{1cm}{0pt}&&& \\
\psframe[style=EAlk](0,-0.05)(0.4,0.35) \hspace{0.5cm} Erdalkalimetalle &&&& \\
\psframe[style=Metall](0,-0.05)(0.4,0.35) \hspace{0.5cm} Metalle        &&Ordnungszahl\hfill\rput(0,0.13){\rnode[cc]{OZA}{}}&&
\rput[l](4.7,0.13){\rnode[lc]{MZA}{Massenzahl}} \\
\psframe[style=HalbMet](0,-0.05)(0.4,0.35) \hspace{0.5cm} Halbmetalle   &&& \rput[l](1,-0.2){\ElementLegende{\rnode{OZB}{}6}{12,011\rnode{MZB}{}}{%
\rnode{ESB}{}C}{\rnode{ENB}{}Kohlenstoff}{2,5\rnode{ENGB}{}}{NoMetal}} &\\
\psframe[style=NoMetal](0,-0.05)(0.4,0.35) \hspace{0.5cm} Nichtmetalle &&\rput[l](0,0.3){Elementsymbol\rput(0,0.13){\rnode{ESA}{}}}&& \\
\psframe[style=Halogen](0,-0.05)(0.4,0.35) \hspace{0.5cm} Halogene      &&&&
\rput[l](4.7,0.4){\rnode[lc]{ENGA}{Elektronegativit\"{a}t}}\\
\psframe[style=Edel](0,-0.05)(0.4,0.35) \hspace{0.5cm} Edelgase         &&
\rput[l](0,0.45){Elementname\rput(0,0.13){\rnode{ENA}{}}}&& \\
\psframe[style=LantAct](0,-0.05)(0.4,0.35) \hspace{0.5cm} Lanthanoide/Actinoide &&&&
\end{tabular}
\pcline[nodesep=0.1](OZA)(OZB|OZA)
\pcline[nodesep=0.1](MZA)(MZB|MZA)
\pcline[nodesep=0.1](ESA)(ESB|ESA)
\pcline[nodesep=0.1](ENA)(ENB|ENA)
\pcline[nodesep=0.1](ENGA)(ENGB|ENGA)
}
}
\rput[l](13,5.0){%
\psshadowbox[
framearc=0.05,
framesep=2.5pt,
fillcolor=orange!10,
linewidth=0.2pt,
linecolor=magenta,
fillstyle=solid,
shadowcolor=magenta!10,
shadowsize=2pt,
shadowangle=45,
]{%
\psscalebox{.5}{%
\begin{tabular}{Dl}
\textbf{\LARGE C}&Feste Elemente \\[4pt]
\textcolor{red}{\textbf{\LARGE He}}&Gasf\"{o}rmige Elemente \\[4pt]
\textcolor{blue!90!black!70}{\textbf{\LARGE Br}}&Fl\"{u}ssige Elemente \\[4pt]
\fuellschrift{Po}&Radioaktive Elemente
\end{tabular}
}}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
%
%-------------------------------- Periodensystem ---------------------------------------
\psscalebox{0.55}{%
\begin{tabular}{>{\Large}p{0.75cm}*{18}{C}}
&\rput(0,0.3){1 IA}
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
& \rput(0,0.3){18 VIIIA}\\
%------------- 1. Periode --------------------------------------
\rput(0,1.35){1}
&\Element{1}{1,0079}{\textcolor{\Gase}{H}}{Wasserstoff}{2,1}{Wst}
&\rput(0,0.3){2 IIA}
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&\rput(0,0.3){13 IIIA}
&\rput(0,0.3){14 IVA}
&\rput(0,0.3){15 VA}
&\rput(0,0.3){16 VIA}
&\rput(0,0.3){17 VIIA}
& \Element{2}{4,0026}{\textcolor{\Gase}{He}}{Helium}{}{Edel}\\
%------------- 2. Periode --------------------------------------
\rput(0,1.35){2}
&\Element{3}{6,941}{Li}{Lithium}{1,0}{Alk}
&\Element{4}{9,0122}{Be}{Beryllium}{1,5}{EAlk}
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&
&\Element{5}{10,811}{B}{Bor}{2,0}{HalbMet}
&\Element{6}{12,011}{C}{Kohlenstoff}{2,5}{NoMetal}
&\Element{7}{14,007}{\textcolor{\Gase}{N}}{Stickstoff}{3,0}{NoMetal}
&\Element{8}{15,999}{\textcolor{\Gase}{O}}{Sauerstoff}{3,5}{NoMetal}
&\Element{9}{18,988}{\textcolor{\Gase}{F}}{Fluor}{4}{Halogen}
&\Element{10}{20,180}{\textcolor{\Gase}{Ne}}{Neon}{}{Edel}\\
%------------- 3. Periode --------------------------------------
\rput(0,1.35){3}
&\Element{11}{22,990}{Na}{Natrium}{0,9}{Alk}
&\Element{12}{24,305}{Mg}{Magnesium}{1,2}{EAlk}
&\rput(0,0.3){3 IIIA}
&\rput(0,0.3){4 IVB}
&\rput(0,0.3){5 VB}
&\rput(0,0.3){6 VIB}
&\rput(0,0.3){7 VIIB}
&\rput(0,0.3){8 VIIIB}
&\rput(0,0.3){9 VIIIB}
&\rput(0,0.3){10 VIIIB}
&\rput(0,0.3){11 IB}
&\rput(0,0.3){12 IIB}
&\Element{13}{26,982}{Al}{Aluminium}{1,5}{Metall}
&\Element{14}{28,086}{Si}{Silicium}{1,8}{HalbMet}
&\Element{15}{30,974}{P}{Phosphor}{2,1}{NoMetal}
&\Element{16}{32,065}{S}{Schwefel}{2,5}{NoMetal}
&\Element{17}{35,453}{\textcolor{\Gase}{Cl}}{Clor}{3,0}{Halogen}
&\Element{18}{39,948}{\textcolor{\Gase}{Ar}}{Argon}{}{Edel}\\
%------------- 4. Periode --------------------------------------
\rput(0,1.35){4}
&\Element{19}{39,098}{K}{Kalium}{0,8}{Alk}
&\Element{20}{40,078}{Ca}{Calcium}{1,0}{EAlk}
&\Element{21}{44,956}{Sc}{Scandium}{1,3}{Metall}
&\Element{22}{47,867}{Ti}{Titan}{1,5}{Metall}
&\Element{23}{50,942}{V}{Vanadium}{1,6}{Metall}
&\Element{24}{51,996}{Cr}{Chrom}{1,6}{Metall}
&\Element{25}{54,938}{Mn}{Mangan}{1,5}{Metall}
&\Element{26}{55,845}{Fe}{Eisen}{1,8}{Metall}
&\Element{27}{58,933}{Co}{Cobalt}{1,8}{Metall}
&\Element{28}{58,693}{Ni}{Nickel}{1,8}{Metall}
&\Element{29}{63,546}{Cu}{Kupfer}{1,9}{Metall}
&\Element{30}{65,381}{Zn}{Zink}{1,6}{Metall}
&\Element{31}{69,723}{Ga}{Gallium}{1,6}{Metall}
&\Element{32}{72,64}{Ge}{Germanium}{1,8}{HalbMet}
&\Element{33}{74,922}{As}{Arsen}{2,0}{HalbMet}
&\Element{34}{78,961}{Se}{Selen}{2,4}{NoMetal}
&\Element{35}{79,904}{\textcolor{\Fluessig}{Br}}{Brom}{2,8}{Halogen}
&\Element{36}{83,798}{\textcolor{\Gase}{Kr}}{Krypton}{}{Edel}\\
%------------- 5. Periode --------------------------------------
\rput(0,1.35){5}
&\Element{37}{85,468}{Rb}{Rubidium}{0,8}{Alk}
&\Element{38}{87,62}{Sr}{Strontium}{1,0}{EAlk}
&\Element{39}{88,906}{Y}{Yttrium}{1,3}{Metall}
&\Element{40}{91,224}{Zr}{Zirconium}{1,4}{Metall}
&\Element{41}{92,906}{Nb}{Niob}{1,6}{Metall}
&\Element{42}{95,96}{Mo}{Molybd\"{a}n}{1,8}{Metall}
&\Element{43}{98,91}{\fuellschrift{Tc}}{Technetium}{1,9}{Metall}
&\Element{44}{101,07}{Ru}{Ruthenium}{2,2}{Metall}
&\Element{45}{102,91}{Rh}{Rhodium}{2,2}{Metall}
&\Element{46}{106,42}{Pd}{Palladium}{2,2}{Metall}
&\Element{47}{107,87}{Ag}{Silber}{1,9}{Metall}
&\Element{48}{112,41}{Cd}{Cadmium}{1,7}{Metall}
&\Element{49}{114,82}{In}{Indium}{1,7}{Metall}
&\Element{50}{118,71}{Sn}{Zinn}{1,8}{Metall}
&\Element{51}{121,76}{Sb}{Antimon}{1,9}{HalbMet}
&\Element{52}{127,60}{Te}{Tellur}{2,1}{HalbMet}
&\Element{53}{126,90}{I}{Iod}{2,5}{Halogen}
&\Element{54}{131,29}{\textcolor{\Gase}{Xe}}{Xenon}{}{Edel}\\
%------------- 6. Periode --------------------------------------
\rput(0,1.35){6}
&\Element{55}{132,91}{Cs}{C\"{a}sium}{0,7}{Alk}
&\Element{56}{137,33}{Ba}{Barium}{0,9}{EAlk}
&\Element{}{}{\rput(0,0.85){\scriptsize\textbf{57 - 71}}\rput(0,0){La-Lu}}{Lanthanide}{}{LantAct}
&\Element{72}{178,49}{Hf}{Hafnium}{1,3}{Metall}
&\Element{73}{180,95}{Ta}{Tantal}{1,5}{Metall}
&\Element{74}{183,84}{W}{Wolfram}{1,7}{Metall}
&\Element{75}{186,21}{Re}{Rhenium}{1,9}{Metall}
&\Element{76}{190,23}{Os}{Osmium}{2,2}{Metall}
&\Element{77}{192,22}{Ir}{Iridium}{2,2}{Metall}
&\Element{78}{195,08}{Pt}{Platin}{2,2}{Metall}
&\Element{79}{196,97}{Au}{Gold}{2,4}{Metall}
&\Element{80}{200,59}{\textcolor{\Fluessig}{Hg}}{Quecksilber}{1,9}{Metall}
&\Element{81}{204,38}{Tl}{Thallium}{1,8}{Metall}
&\Element{82}{207,2}{Pb}{Blei}{1,8}{Metall}
&\Element{83}{208,98}{Bi}{Bismut}{1,9}{Metall}
&\Element{84}{209,98}{\fuellschrift{Po}}{Polonium}{2,0}{HalbMet}
&\Element{85}{210}{\fuellschrift{At}}{Astat}{2,2}{Halogen}
&\Element{86}{222}{\fuellschrift{Rn}}{Radon}{}{Edel}\\
%------------- 7. Periode --------------------------------------
\rput(0,1.35){7}
&\Element{87}{223}{\fuellschrift{Fr}}{Francium}{0,7}{Alk}
&\Element{88}{226,03}{\fuellschrift{Ra}}{Radium}{0,9}{EAlk}
&\Element{}{}{\rput(0,0.85){\scriptsize\textbf{89 - 103}}\rput(0,0){Ac-Lr}}{Actinide}{}{LantAct}
&\Element{104}{261}{\fuellschrift{Rf}}{Rutherfordium}{}{Metall}
&\Element{105}{262}{\fuellschrift{Db}}{Dubnium}{}{Metall}
&\Element{106}{263}{\fuellschrift{Sg}}{Seaborgium}{}{Metall}
&\Element{107}{262}{\fuellschrift{Bh}}{Bohrium}{}{Metall}
&\Element{108}{265}{\fuellschrift{Hs}}{Hassium}{}{Metall}
&\Element{109}{266}{\fuellschrift{Mt}}{Meitnerium}{}{Metall}
&\Element{110}{269}{\fuellschrift{Ds}}{Darmstadtium}{}{Metall}
&\Element{111}{272}{\fuellschrift{Rg}}{R\"{o}ntgenium}{}{Metall}
&\Element{112}{277}{\fuellschrift{Cn}}{Copernicium}{}{Metall}
&\Element{113}{287}{\fuellschrift{Uut}}{Ununtrium}{}{Metall}
&\Element{114}{289}{\fuellschrift{Fl}}{Flerovium}{}{Metall}
&\Element{115}{288}{\fuellschrift{Uup}}{Ununpentium}{}{Metall}
&\Element{116}{289}{\fuellschrift{Lv}}{Livermorium}{}{Metall}
&\Element{117}{293}{\fuellschrift{Uus}}{Ununseptium}{}{Wst}
&\Element{118}{294}{\fuellschrift{Uuo}}{Ununoctium}{}{Halogen}\\[2cm]
%------------- Lanthanide --------------------------------------
\rput[r](5.5,1.35){Lanthanide}
&
&
&\Element{57}{138,91}{La}{Lanthan}{1,1}{LantAct}
&\Element{58}{140,12}{Ce}{Cer}{1,1}{LantAct}
&\Element{59}{140,91}{Pr}{Praseodym}{1,1}{LantAct}
&\Element{60}{144,24}{Nd}{Neodym}{1,1}{LantAct}
&\Element{61}{144,90}{\fuellschrift{Pm}}{Promethium}{1,1}{LantAct}
&\Element{62}{150,36}{Sm}{Samarium}{1,2}{LantAct}
&\Element{63}{151,96}{Eu}{Europium}{1,2}{LantAct}
&\Element{64}{157,25}{Gd}{Gadolinium}{1,2}{LantAct}
&\Element{65}{158,93}{Tb}{Terbium}{1,2}{LantAct}
&\Element{66}{162,50}{Dy}{Dysprosium}{1,2}{LantAct}
&\Element{67}{164,93}{Ho}{Holmium}{1,2}{LantAct}
&\Element{68}{167,26}{Er}{Erbium}{1,2}{LantAct}
&\Element{69}{168,93}{Tm}{Thulium}{1,2}{LantAct}
&\Element{70}{173,05}{Yb}{Ytterbium}{1,2}{LantAct}
&\Element{71}{174,97}{Lu}{Lutetium}{1,2}{LantAct}
&\\[0.3cm]
%------------- Actinide --------------------------------------
\rput[r](5.5,1.35){Actinide}
&
&
&\Element{89}{227}{\fuellschrift{Ac}}{Actinium}{1,1}{LantAct}
&\Element{90}{232,04}{\fuellschrift{Th}}{Thorium}{1,3}{LantAct}
&\Element{91}{231,04}{\fuellschrift{Pa}}{Protaktinium}{1,5}{LantAct}
&\Element{92}{238,03}{\fuellschrift{U}}{Uran}{1,4}{LantAct}
&\Element{93}{237,05}{\fuellschrift{Np}}{Neptunium}{1,3}{LantAct}
&\Element{94}{244,10}{\fuellschrift{Pu}}{Plutonium}{1,3}{LantAct}
&\Element{95}{243,10}{\fuellschrift{Am}}{Americium}{1,3}{LantAct}
&\Element{96}{247,10}{\fuellschrift{Cm}}{Curium}{1,3}{LantAct}
&\Element{97}{247,10}{\fuellschrift{Bk}}{Berkelium}{1,3}{LantAct}
&\Element{98}{251,10}{\fuellschrift{Cf}}{Californium}{1,3}{LantAct}
&\Element{99}{254,10}{\fuellschrift{Es}}{Einsteinium}{1,3}{LantAct}
&\Element{100}{257,10}{\fuellschrift{Fm}}{Fermium}{1,3}{LantAct}
&\Element{101}{258}{\fuellschrift{Md}}{Mendelevium}{1,3}{LantAct}
&\Element{102}{259}{\fuellschrift{No}}{Nobelium}{1,3}{LantAct}
&\Element{103}{260}{\fuellschrift{Lr}}{Lawrencium}{1,3}{LantAct}
&\\
\end{tabular}
}

\end{landscape}


\end{document}


Periodensystem der Elemente
```

**EDITS**

Here are the screenshots of the errors.

I use TEXPAD app with the auto-detect compiling mode.

[image]

[image]

**SOLUTION**

As the guys in the comment say, I used PdFLaTeX to compile. I changed it into what they advised me for, and now it works.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I do not get any errors when I compile this with `latex` to `ps` (and convert the `ps` to `pdf`). I use an updated TeXLive 2019 installation. How do you compile this? Which errors do you get? (Just for the records: I do get errors with `XeLaTeX`.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat --- latex+dvips works for me as well. However, pdflatex reports an error on line 165, and the message includes the string `_Not_Configured_For_This_Format`. Therefore I think the answer is just: use latex+dvips.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I use TexPad app, and when I compile I use the "auto-detect" mode. I am going to upload a screenshot of the errors!

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat --- Indeed. I was just confirming that you have 'hit the nail on the head' so to speak; the OP mentioned an error on line 165, and pdflatex reports an error on the same line. So my guess is that Henry is attempting to compile with pdflatex.

Comment: @IanThompson Oh, I see. Sorry! I didn't read your comment carefully enough. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Waaaait! It compiles. You were right, I used PdFLaTeX. I changed it and it works now!

Comment: Note you have an old tex installation you get a  more understandable error message than undefined `\c@lor@to@ps` if you try the same on a current version of pstricks.

Comment: Although using a completely different example code, our current question seems to be quite similar to this possible duplicate [PSTricks error “Undefined control sequence <recently read> \c@lor@to@ps”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68870/134144). Would you agree closing yours as a duplicate to the linked one?